# How to uncheck the default value of an attribute in magento admin panel

Tags: magento, admin

Is there any way to uncheck the default value of an attribute in magento admin panel ?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this in the database:

- Go to table `eav_attribute`
- Search the row of your attribute ("charge" in your case)
- Set column `default_value` to NULL

Login credentials for your database can be found in `app/etc/local.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Just removed the default off a attribute by creating a new dummy attribute, selecting this as the default and then deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Just Inspect the radio button and remove this ( checked='"checked"/' ) from input tag, press enter. it will be deselected and then save the attribute.